# How to calculate a username in my event_participant table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT a.event_name AS event_name, a.event_date AS event_date,
       a.event_venue AS event_venue, a.event_tparticipant AS event_tparticipant,
       b.username AS username 
FROM (SELECT * FROM event WHERE status = 'valid') AS a
JOIN
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT username) AS username
    FROM event_participant
    GROUP BY event_name
) AS b
GROUP BY event_name desc
```

My problem is when it count a username, its not the exact amount on my database. Please help me

Comment: As has probably been pointed out already, you are missing a join condition in your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is missing a `join` condition. Try the one below.

```
SELECT 
a.event_name as event_name, a.event_date as event_date, 
a.event_venue as event_venue, 
a.event_tparticipant as event_tparticipant, 
b.username as username 
FROM (select * from event WHERE status='valid') as a
JOIN (select event_name, COUNT(DISTINCT username) as username
      from event_participant
      GROUP BY event_name) as b
ON a.event_name = b.event_name --change this condition to be appropriate
GROUP BY event_name desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would be a more traditional approach...

```
SELECT 
    a.event_name as event_name, a.event_date as event_date, a.event_venue as event_venue, a.event_tparticipant as event_tparticipant
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT b.username) as username 
FROM
    event_participant b
    JOIN event a ON a.event_name = b.event_name
WHERE
    a.status = 'valid'
GROUP BY 
    a.event_name as event_name, a.event_date as event_date, a.event_venue as event_venue, a.event_tparticipant as event_tparticipant
ORDER BY
    a.event_name desc
```

...though joining on an event_id (if there is such a thing) would be better